# PHP create from one array multiple json files of given size

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create multiple json files (file1.json, file2.json, etc.) from one array and each file must have max file size 5 mb.

I have this kind of array:

```
    array (
    0 => array (
        'category' => '179535',
        'email' => NULL,
        'level' => 1,
        'name' => 'FOO'
    ),
    1 => array (
        'category' => '1795',
        'email' => NULL,
        'level' => 1,
        'name' => 'BARFOO'
    ),
    2 => array (
        'category' => '16985',
        'email' => NULL,
        'level' => 1,
        'name' => 'FOOBAR'
    ),
    ....
    
    25500 => array (
        'category' => '10055',
        'email' => NULL,
        'level' => 1,
        'name' => 'FOOBARBAR'
    )    
)
```

If I write it in a file with json_encode($arr). The resulting file will be approximately 85mb. So how can I split this array to have a maximum of 5 mb per file?

Comment: Can you show some more. How do you create the file presently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700307/splitting-a-file-for-upload-via-php

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most performance-friendly option, assuming your data is reasonably symmetric, would be to simply use [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to cut your array into chunks that, when `json_encode`d, will be approximately the expected size. Let's look at a sampling from your array:

```
string(58) "{"category":"1795","email":null,"level":1,"name":"BARFOO"}"
```

The "name" here seems to be the only one likely to vary more significantly. Let's average it at 12 characters, you'd have a string length of 64 bytes per item. Then, you could fit 78125 of those into 5MB. To keep it under the mark, let's make it 75000. Then, `$chunks = array_chunk($data, 75000)` would give you X chunks that'd be around or a bit under the 5MB mark.

Now, if you wanted to be more precise, and if the size really matters... We can:

```
$size = 0; // size counter
$chunkno = 1; // chunk number
$maxbytes = 50000; // 50000-byte chunks
$chunks = []; // for array chunks

foreach($data as $set) {
    // if over the limit, move on to next chunk
    if ($size > $maxbytes) { 
        $size = 0;
        $chunkno++;
    }
    $size += strlen(json_encode($set)) + 1; // add a comma's length!
    $chunks[$chunkno][] = $set;
}
// unset($data); // in case you have memory concerns
```

Here we're obviously doing double-duty with the json_encode, but chunk size will not be impacted by variance in your source data. I ran the test script above for 50000-byte chunks, you'll want to have `5000000` instead for your use case. The dummy data I generated split into neat 50K chunks, max. +/- size of one set, plus the remainder in the last file.

While mulling over this, I also played with the thought of doing `strlen(implode(` instead, but given the generally great performance of PHP's `json_encode`, there shouldn't be much of a penalty there, for the trade-off for getting the exact JSON string size.

In any case, once the chunks are ready, all we need to do is write 'em up:

```
foreach($chunks as $n => $chunk) {
    $json = json_encode($chunk);
    file_put_contents("tmp/chunk_{$n}.json", $json);
}
```

... or matching whatever your chunk naming and directory schema may be.

Perhaps there are more clever ways of doing this. That said, as far as I'm aware, nothing in core PHP will do this sort of an operation out of the box (even for vanilla arrays), and the above should perform reasonably well. Remember to have enough memory available. :)

P.S. In calculating the size, we add +1 for each item, standing for `{},{},{}`, or the object delimiters. Strictly speaking, you'd also want to add +2 to the grand total, because it'll be `[{},{},{}]`, while we're only counting the length of each array item as a separate JSON object. With other data structures, your compensation mileage may vary.

---

**Optimization Update:** If you choose the "exact size" approach and want to optimize memory usage, you're better off integrating the JSON commit into the chunking loop. (Thanks @NigelRen for the suggestion.) As follows (other initial variables as before):

```
$chunk = [];
foreach($data as $n => $set) {
    if ($size > $maxbytes) {
        file_put_contents("tmp/chunk_{$chunkno}.json", json_encode($chunk));
        $chunk = [];
        $chunkno++;
        $size = 0;
    }
    $size += strlen(json_encode($set)) + 1;
    $chunk[] = $set;
    //  unset($data[$n]); // in case of memory issues, see notes
}
```

In case you're curious over the impact. With this approach, memory usage comes to (used, max) 1.06 MB, 29.34 MB. With the separate write routine, 26.29 MB, 31.8 MB. Both figures include the `unset($data)` call, nixing the initial array and freeing up memory. CPU-wise, no significant difference between the two options.

One could also purge members of the `$data` array each time after adding to the `$chunk[]`, however at 5MB chunk size the memory benefit here is negligible. It's the loading/defining of the initial array itself that's expensive, being the major factor in the max memory usage figure. (The test array I used occupied 29.25 MB before any processing began.)

Comment: If it works then probably better than chunking entire array.

Comment: Why store the set of chunks, as you fill up a chunk, write it out and clear the data to start again.

Comment: @NigelRen I wrote the write-loop separately to have it "plug and play" with the `array_chunk` option, but you're right, it'd be more memory-efficient to commit and clean in the `if ($size > $maxbytes)` check. Have added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `strlen` in Bytes and do your calculations from there:

```
$total_size  = strlen(json_encode($array)) / 1024 / 1024;
$chunk_size  = floor($total_size / 5);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($array, $chunk_size);    

foreach($chunked_array as $key => $chunk) {
    $i = $key + 1;
    file_put_contents("file{$i}.json", json_encode($chunk));
}
```

- Get the total size in Bytes of the JSON encoded array and convert to MB
- Divide that total size by 5MB to get chunk size
- Chunk the array into chunk size
- Loop and JSON encode each chunk and write to file

Or for the calculation you could do:

```
$total_size  = strlen(json_encode($array));
$chunk_size  = floor($total_size / (5 * 1024 * 1024));
```

Comment: +1 for factoring the array chunk size from the total `strlen` of the array. This approach of course presumes a consistent data structure and reasonably stable value lengths.

Comment: Thanks, yeah was a quick thought, would be better to incrementally add size of each array up to max.

Comment: I choose @MarkusAO  answer because it has several explanations, so I managed to understand why I did not know how to use strlen, which was my the first option in the php manual. Thank you.

Comment: @DGA thing with `strlen` is, even if you were to `array_map('strlen'...`, is that it casts everything to strings (and will throw a fit if you feed it other than scalars). Then, `array_sum(array_map('strlen', ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, true, null]))` is 6. Also, with this approach, you'd also have to calculate the bytes that go into named index keys for each item. And, of course, calculate any other JSON markup overhead (+2 bytes for strings' quotes vs. integers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that each  item has the same structure thus:

> 1500 items ~= 5MB

```
 25500 items = ~85MB

 85MB / 5MB = 17 
 
 25500 / 17 = 1500 items
```

code can be something like that:

```
foreach(array_chunk($array, 1500) as $arr){

 // save array in some file

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this work around:

```
<?php
    $array = array (
        0 => array (
            'category' => '179535',
            'email' => NULL,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'FOO'
        ),
        1 => array (
            'category' => '1795',
            'email' => NULL,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'BARFOO'
        ),
        2 => array (
            'category' => '16985',
            'email' => NULL,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'FOOBAR'
        )
    );

    $len = sizeof($array);
    $fileNameIndex = 1;
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    {
        $fileName = 'file'.$fileNameIndex.'.json';
        $fileExist = file_exists($fileName);
        $fileSize = 0;
        $mode ='w';
        $current = null;
        if($fileExist)
        {
            $fileSize = fileSize($fileName);
            $current = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
        }
        if($fileExist && $fileSize < 5242880)
        {
            WriteToFile($fileNameIndex, $current, $array[$i], $i);
        }
        else if(!$fileExist)
        {
            WriteToFile($fileNameIndex, $current, $array[$i], $i);
        }
        else
        {
            $fileNameIndex ++;
            WriteToFile($fileNameIndex, $current, $array[$i], $i);
        }
    }

    function WriteToFile($fileNameIndex, $current, $data, $i)
    {
        $fileName = 'file'.$fileNameIndex.'.json';
        $mode ='w';
        echo "$i index array is being written in $fileName. <br/>";
        $fileNameIndex ++;
        $fp = fopen($fileName, $mode);
        if($current)
        {
            array_push($current, $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $current = [];
            array_push($current, $data);
        }
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($current));
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Won't this be awfully expensive, when you're doing `file_exists()`, `filesize()` and `file_get_contents()` for `sizeof($array)` times in a loop?